# How do I prove that group $B(v) = \{x : \|x\| \leq 1\}$ contains an ellipsoid around the axes?

Tags: convex-analysis, ellipsoids

I have no idea on where to begin. Also, I have to prove that the aforementioned set is convex, which I tried by contradicting, and I'm having difficulty with that as well. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to add a lot more information. How is $B(v)$ a group? do you mean $B(v)=\{x\mid \|x\|\leq 1\}\subset V$ for some normed space $V$? What is $v$ in the notation for $B(v)$? What are the axes (presumably this refers to the space $V$ which you have not mentioned)?

Comment: I mean exactly what you said, I'm a little bit new to this, sorry for the confusion. The axes aren't mentioned in the question, is it safe to assume that the point is just $0$?